# Gradle Build Failed For Task app:processReleaseResources

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nusecond.karun.suredeal"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("suredealreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "suredeal"
            keyAlias "SuredealReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "suredeal"
        }
    }


buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'

    /**
     * GSON
     */
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    // UI AutomatorTesting
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'

    /**
     * Spring Dependencies
     * compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
     * compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
     * compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
     */
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'

    /**
     * Android Annotation Dependencies
     */
    compile 'org.glassfish.main:javax.annotation:4.0-b33'

    /**
     * Volley Jar
     */
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    /**
     * GCM Dependency
     */
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    /**
     * Universal image Loader
     */
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}
```

1. This is build.gradle
2. Here I'm generating signed APK using Gradle Build.(`./gradlew assembleRelease`).
   3.Build Failed for task app:processReleaseResources.

Here the stacktrace:

```
----------
./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> at index 4

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 4
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:240)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:231)
    at com.google.common.collect.ObjectArrays.checkElementsNotNull(ObjectArrays.java:226)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:303)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:258)
    at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder.createProcess(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.core.AaptPackageProcessBuilder.build(AaptPackageProcessBuilder.java:444)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:915)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 49 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.696 secs
```

I'm stuck here Any solution How to fix this issue plz Help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I got solution for this issue after going through so many articles.

This issue is because of sdk tools Version mismatch.

The targeted sdk version in build.gradle file must match with the sdk version which you installed.

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle,

```
applicationId "com.company.app"
```

Should match in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
package="com.company.app"
```

I was getting this same error because they didn't match.

Answer (score 2):

My solution came from here

REMOVE ALL IMAGES FROM RES/ DRAWABLE THAT YOU DON'T NEED

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19239

Credit for --> ZeroCool00

For those who are doing this before generating apk

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

it generate unnecessary drawable images in drawable folder. so make sure to remove it and try again.

android-> app -> src -> main -> res -> drawable

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a to long (more that 100 chars) name of a file in Assets

Answer (score 0):

> After so much searching, I found this solution

In **android/gradle.properties**
add
`android.enableAapt2=false`

Answer (score 0):

*for cordova projects*

adding the cordova plugin `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` has fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was being caused by a circular reference in an xml file. Lint would usually flag the issue, unless instructed not too.
Check for:

```
tools:ignore="ResourceCycle"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was adding  tag inside application tag thats why it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

*( CREDITS TO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52wKo4rNG_o )*

**Just in case this helps someone.**

When I was trying to sign my app I was having this problem:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/aaa/StudioProjects/aaa/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.aaa.aaa:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
     /Users/aaa/StudioProjects/aaa/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.aaa.aaa:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

It was caused because each of the resources that I had created for my application were created exclusively for the "debug" environment, since by default this is selected for each resource in android studio.

[First approach to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNec7.png)

To solve it I just created each of the resources again but now making sure that they were created in "main" and not in "debug" like this

[Solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbthK.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the resource is created in debug mode.

[image]

To fix this:
click on drawable folder -> new -> new drawable resource -> give same file name to the original -> make sure to select main in the drop down -> create file -> now copy paste the contents from the original file onto this file.

Answer (score -1):

My method is always try the simplest potential solution: and I added this line inside gradle.properties in the app folder:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

It works wonder exactly no issue.