# Android Studio - Signed SDK, task failed 'android:mergeReleaseResources"

Tags: android, apk

As the title says, when I run Build->Generate signed APK (The APK I am going to upload to the google play store) -> Build Type = release, Signature  V1 and V2 both checked -> Finish I get the error

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':android:mergeReleaseResources'

I have googled for quite some time and can't find another person who had the same exact error as me.

I have a correctly generated Keystore, the passwords are correct (I have seen the error the gradle spits out when its an incorrect password, and it's different)

I have the log coppied to a google doc if you want to take a look. I don't understand log language... https://docs.google.com/document/d/10jr5y9bxCPuNsB484k2Gysv4MeMs4pNJK8oBVMuYMLA/edit?usp=sharing

What does this error message mean, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it reads `java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com` ...while that log might be way easier to read in landscape layout, possibly with a smaller font.

Comment: sir can u attach full logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Build Failed For Task app:processReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407479/gradle-build-failed-for-task-appprocessreleaseresources)